# Java - How to 'return' a value in a class

Tags: java, class, return

I am trying to assign a value or return a value in a class. Something like this:

```
void setOff() {

    boolean onValue = true;

    Thread t = new Thread(new myClass(onValue));

    System.out.println("On: " + onValue);

}

class myClass implements Runnable{

    public boolean on;

    public myClass (boolean _on) {

        on = _on

    }

    public run() {

        on = false;

    }

}
```

Is something like that possible? Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for an assign-by-reference behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to change your code a bit. Check the following classes:

- **[`Callable<V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)**
- **[`FutureTask<V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)**

The first one is something like a `Runnable`, but the method you need to implement is defined as `V call() throws Exception`, instead of `void run()`: it allows you to return a value.

The second one wraps a `Callable<V>` (or a `Runnable` plus a constant return value), and is a `Runnable` itself, so you can pass it to a `Thread` just like you were doing with your `Runnable`.

So, you could change your code to something like the following:

```
void setOff() {
  final FutureTask<Boolean> ft = new FutureTask<Boolean>(new myClass());
  new Thread(ft).start();
  try {
    System.out.println("The result is: " + ft.get());
  } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    System.err.println("A method executed on the background thread has thrown an exception");
    e.getCause().printStackTrack();
  }
}

class myClass implements Callable<Boolean> {
  @Override public Boolean call() throws Exception {
    // let's fake some long running computation:
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    return true;
  }
}
```

The call `ft.get()` will only return after the `call()` method finishes executing (on the background thread), so you will have to wait 1 second before the line gets printed to the console.

There are many other useful methods on `FutureTask`. Check [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html).

There are some other classes that you may find useful: **[`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)** and its implementations, and the factory methods in **[`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)**. It has a method called `submit` which accepts a `Runnable` or a `Callable<V>`, and returns a `Future<?>` or `Future<V>`, which is one of the interfaces implemented by `FutureTask`. You get a similar behaviour. For example:

```
public static void main() {
  final ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
  final Future<Boolean> f = es.submit(new myClass());
  try {
    System.out.println("The result is: " + f.get());
  } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    System.err.println("A method executed on the background thread has thrown an exception");
    e.getCause().printStackTrack();
  }
  es.shutdown();
}
```

The advantage of this is that the [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) will manage the threads for you. It may create some threads and reuse them for the Callables and Runnables you submit: this will possibly improve performance if you have many such jobs, since you will avoid creating one thread per job -- thread creation has some overhead!

**EDIT**: the `.get()` method throws an `ExecutionException`, which wraps an exception that might get thrown during the execution of the `.call()` method. To inspect the exception, `catch` the `ExecutionException` and call `.getCause()` on it. I've just added the missing try/catch block.

Comment: @01100011_0101011_0101011 generics are nice. You will love generics.

Comment: Yes, generics... they are a blessing and a PITA.